# Можно ли использовать CSS translateX (100%) для создания движущейся анимации?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animation

В своей анимации мне нравится использовать трансформацию. Это также возможно сделать со свойством `left / right`. Но мне нравится использовать `transform`. Мне нужно переместить `freeze-loading-bar` на 100% вправо, и это должен быть бесконечный цикл.

Как я могу переместить полосу загрузки вправо на 100% / полностью?

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.app-view {
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px 0 #e0e0e0ad, 1px -1px 9px 0 #dddddd2e;

  padding: 2rem;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.freeze-loading {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 4px 0 #ddd;
  
  /** disual purpose **/
  /** overflow: hidden; **/
  
}

.freeze-loading-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
  animation: freeze-loading-bar 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes freeze-loading-bar {
    from {
        transform: translateX(-100px);
    }

    to {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="app-view">
  <div class="freeze-loading">
    <div class="freeze-loading-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Is it possible to use CSS translateX(100%) to make a moving animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62500463/7394871) от участника  [@Tahazzot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12661546/tahazzot).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62500463/7394871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сохраняйте элемент на всю ширину (используя left/right), затем используйте градиент для окраски, чтобы раскрасить только его часть. Теперь вы можете положиться на `translateX(100%)` независимо от ширины раскраски:

```css
.freeze-loading {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  height: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 4px 0 #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.freeze-loading-bar {
  --w:80px;  /* ширина окраски */

  position: absolute;
  left: calc(-1*var(--w));
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background:
   linear-gradient(rgb(0, 132, 255) 0 0) 
   0 / var(--w) 100%  
   no-repeat;
   animation: freeze-loading-bar 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes freeze-loading-bar {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="freeze-loading">
  <div class="freeze-loading-bar"></div>
</div>

<div class="freeze-loading">
  <div class="freeze-loading-bar" style="--w:150px;"></div>
</div>
```

Другой вид анимации:

```css
.freeze-loading {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  height: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 4px 0 #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.freeze-loading-bar {
  --w:80px; /* the width of coloration */

  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: var(--w);
  height: 100%;
  background:
   linear-gradient(rgb(0, 132, 255) 0 0) 
   0 / var(--w) 100%  
   no-repeat;
   animation: freeze-loading-bar 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes freeze-loading-bar {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="freeze-loading">
  <div class="freeze-loading-bar"></div>
</div>

<div class="freeze-loading">
  <div class="freeze-loading-bar" style="--w:150px;"></div>
</div>
```

---

Другой синтаксис:

```css
.freeze-loading {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  height: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 4px 0 #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.freeze-loading-bar {
  --w:80px;  /* the width of coloration */

  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background:
   linear-gradient(rgb(0, 132, 255) 0 0) 
   0 / var(--w) 100%  
   no-repeat;
  animation: freeze-loading-bar 2s linear infinite;
  transform: translateX(calc(-1*var(--w)));
}

@keyframes freeze-loading-bar {
  to  {
     transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="freeze-loading">
  <div class="freeze-loading-bar"></div>
</div>

<div class="freeze-loading">
  <div class="freeze-loading-bar" style="--w:150px;"></div>
</div>
```

И еще один пример:

```css
.freeze-loading {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  height: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 4px 0 #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.freeze-loading-bar {
  --w:80px;  /* the width of coloration */

  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width:calc(100% + var(--w));
  height: 100%;
  background:
   linear-gradient(rgb(0, 132, 255) 0 0) 
   0 / var(--w) 100%  
   no-repeat;
  animation: freeze-loading-bar 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes freeze-loading-bar {
  to  {
     transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="freeze-loading">
  <div class="freeze-loading-bar"></div>
</div>

<div class="freeze-loading">
  <div class="freeze-loading-bar" style="--w:150px;"></div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62500656/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

С точки зрения отзывчивости используйте `%`, а не `px`, чем проста математика,

Если **width** полосы составляет **20%** (1/**5** родительской)

`translateX` from `-100%` to `500%` (100% * **5**)

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.app-view {
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px 0 #e0e0e0ad, 1px -1px 9px 0 #dddddd2e;
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.freeze-loading {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 4px 0 #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.freeze-loading-bar {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
  animation: freeze-loading-bar 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes freeze-loading-bar {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(500%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="app-view">
  <div class="freeze-loading">
    <div class="freeze-loading-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62500592/7394871) от участника  [@Roko C. Buljan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383904/roko-c-buljan).</sub>